# How to show image in table in laravel backpack

Tags: laravel-5.8, laravel-backpack

I am getting trouble to view image in table in laravel-backpack. After creating image crud only filename is shown. But I want to show image in the table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [image column type](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/crud-columns#image). In your ProductCrudController, for example, you'd do:

```php
protected function setupListOperation()
{
    // ...

    $this->crud->addColumn([
      'name' => 'profile_image', // The db column name
      'label' => "Profile image", // Table column heading
      'type' => 'image',

      // OPTIONALS
      // 'prefix' => 'folder/subfolder/',
      // image from a different disk (like s3 bucket)
      // 'disk' => 'disk-name', 

      // optional width/height if 25px is not ok with you
      // 'height' => '30px',
      // 'width' => '30px',
    ]);

    // ...
}
```